# char pointer pointing to a char array

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 char a[3];
 char *b=NULL;
 a[0]=0;
 a[1]=1;
 a[2]=2;
 b = a;
 printf("%c",b);
 b++;
 printf("%c",b);
 b++;
 printf("%c",b);
 return 0;
}
```

I tried to print the values 0,1,2 by incrementing the pointer by 1. please help

Comment: Sounds like homework. What's your analysis of the problem so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%c` tells `printf` to interpret the `char` argument as a character code (most likely ASCII).  Use `%d` instead.

Answer (score 4):

b is a pointer in itself, you have to dereference it to get the actual values:

```
printf("%d", *b);
b++;
printf("%d", *b);
b++;
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 char a[3];
 char *b=NULL;
 a[0]='0';
 a[1]='1';
 a[2]='2';
 b = a;
 printf("%c",*b);
 b++;
 printf("%c",*b);
 b++;
 printf("%c",*b);
 return 0;
}
```